# How to get 3d coordinates from a 3d object file.

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, blender

I am using 3 ArUco Markers stuck on a 3D head phantom model to do pose estimation using OpenCV in C++. My algorithm for pose estimation is giving me the translation with respect to the camera, but I want to now know the coordinates of the marker with respect to the model coordinate system. Therefore I have scanned the head model using a 3D scanner and have an object file and the texture file with me. My question is what is the easiest or best way to get the coordinates of the markers with respect to the head model. Should I use OpenGL, blender or some other software for it? Looking for some pointers or advice.

Comment: too broad, unclear and vague without any sample input so we can only guess that you want to cross match similar meshes and estimate relative transform matrix to translate between them. That is huge topic and without seeing your case is hard to help... at least add screenshots of the 2 meshes/PCLs Anyway either identify specific feature (like nose or chin, ears)  and create the matrices from their locations or use SIFT/SURF like features + RANSAC to cross match. If you got markers use them but they need to have special meaning like known location in both meshes. The title is misleading I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have the coordinates for the markers with respect to the camera as the coordinate system, so coordinates in "eye space" or camera space. Which is when you have coordinates where the camera is at the origin.

This article has a brilliant diagram which explain the different spaces and how to transform in to different spaces:
http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html

If you want these same coordinates but in model space you need the matrices that will get you in to that space.

In this case you are going from eye/camera space -> model space so you need to multiply those coordinates by the inverse view matrix then by the inverse model matrix. Then your coordinate would be in model space.

But this is a lot more difficult when you are using a physical camera, as opposed to a software camera, in OpenGL for example. 
To do that you will need to use OpenCV to obtain your camera's intrinsic and extrinsic parameters. 
See this tutorial for more details:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html